# WPF shortcut key binding

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, keyboard-shortcuts

I want to bind a shortcut key to my usercontrol using 
UserControl.InputBindings.

I am not using MVVM or any other pattern. I just want to bind this key using the code behind file of a XAML file.

Answer (score 1):

You can do key binding like this in XAML:

```
<UserControl.InputBindings>
    <KeyBinding Command="{Binding SomeCommand}" Key="F5"/>
</UserControl.InputBindings>
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. This will bind command as per DataContext and will resolve my issue. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to assign a keybinding, and you want to do it from the code-behind, this would be the easiest way:

```
using System.Windows.Input;

var cmd = new RoutedCommand();
userControl.InputBindings.Add(new KeyBinding(cmd, your_key_gesture_here));
userControl.CommandBindings.Add(new CommandBinding(cmd, your_event_handler_here));
```

Replace `your_key_gesture_here` with the shortcut key you want to trigger, and replace `your_event_handler_here` with the method you want to be triggered when the key is pressed.

Comment: Thank you for the great help. It resolved the issue using code behind file.